# Test functions are dense in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I was wondering about the following: If we say that the test functions are dense in $L^p$, does this imply that there is also always a sequence of them converging pointwise and in $L^p$ norm to such a $f \in L^p$?- I guess this is true and follows from the fact that $L^p$ implies that there is a subsequence converging pointwise a.e., am I right or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: With pointwise convergence **almost everywhere**, your statement (and the proof) are correct. If you want **pointwise** convergence, this is not really well defined, since elements of $L^p$ are only equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: @PhoemueX yes thank you, that is what I meant.